# How to use a ViewGroup as a shared element for a transition animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to set up a *"shared element"* transition animation among two fragments. However, the destination I want is not a single view, but a `FrameLayout` with two overlapped elements that share size (an arrow and a rotating map) and must move and shrink at the same time.

My target layout looks like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_arrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <ar.com.lichtmaier.antenas.ArrowView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

I want to treat all this as a single thing.

Before transitions I was doing this animation on `container_arrow` using scale and translation properties, and it worked fine.

However, when I use a transition the size animation only affects the outer `FrameLayout`, but not its children. The inner arrow moves, but doesn't start small and grows, it start big and stays big. If I target the arrow instead, it works.

Looking at `ChangeBounds` transition code it seems it uses `setFrame()` to directly adjust the bounds of the target element. That doesn't propagate to its children.

I would need the translation+shrink animation to affect two elements, but transition names must be unique. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

EDIT:

I'm already trying to set the FrameLayout as a group by calling:

```
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(arrowContainer, "animatedArrow")
    ViewGroupCompat.setTransitionGroup(arrowContainer, true) // <-- this
```

Same thing.. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own `Transition` subclass which is similar to `ChangeBounds` but uses translation and scale view properties to move the target instead of adjusting bounds. A delta for translation is calculated and it's animated to 0, and an initial scale is also calculated and animated to 1.

Here's the code:

```
class MoveWithScaleAndTranslation : Transition() {

    override fun captureStartValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun captureEndValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun getTransitionProperties() = properties

    private fun captureValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues) {
        val view = transitionValues.view
        val values = transitionValues.values

        val screenLocation = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation)
        values[PROPNAME_POSX] = screenLocation[0]
        values[PROPNAME_POSY] = screenLocation[1]

        values[PROPNAME_WIDTH] = view.width
        values[PROPNAME_HEIGHT] = view.height
    }

    override fun createAnimator(sceneRoot: ViewGroup, startValues: TransitionValues?, endValues: TransitionValues?): Animator? {
        if(startValues == null || endValues == null)
            return null

        val leftDelta = ((startValues.values[PROPNAME_POSX] as Int) - (endValues.values[PROPNAME_POSX] as Int)).toFloat()
        val topDelta = ((startValues.values[PROPNAME_POSY] as Int) - (endValues.values[PROPNAME_POSY] as Int)).toFloat()

        val scaleWidth = (startValues.values[PROPNAME_WIDTH] as Int).toFloat() / (endValues.values[PROPNAME_WIDTH] as Int).toFloat()
        val scaleHeight = (startValues.values[PROPNAME_HEIGHT] as Int).toFloat() / (endValues.values[PROPNAME_HEIGHT] as Int).toFloat()

        val view = endValues.view
        val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", scaleWidth, 1f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", scaleHeight, 1f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", leftDelta, 0f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationY", topDelta, 0f)
        )
        anim.doOnStart {
            view.pivotX = 0f
            view.pivotY = 0f
        }
        return anim
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PROPNAME_POSX = "movewithscaleandtranslation:posX"
        private const val PROPNAME_POSY = "movewithscaleandtranslation:posY"
        private const val PROPNAME_WIDTH = "movewithscaleandtranslation:width"
        private const val PROPNAME_HEIGHT = "movewithscaleandtranslation:height"
        val properties = arrayOf(PROPNAME_POSX, PROPNAME_POSY, PROPNAME_WIDTH, PROPNAME_HEIGHT)
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the exact same problem recently and using this transition instead of the usual move solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what the [`ViewGroupCompat.setTransitionGroup()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewGroupCompat#setTransitionGroup(android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) API (for API 14+ devices when using AndroidX Transition) or [`android:transitionGroup="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#transitionGroup) XML attribute (for API 21+ devices) is for - by setting that flag to true, that entire ViewGroup is used as a single item when it comes to shared element transitions.

Note that you must also set a transition name on the same element you set as a transition group (using `ViewCompat.setTransitionName()` / `android:transitionName` depending on whether you want to support back to API 14 or only API 21+).

Comment: To clarify: the issue was not that the views moved independently, but that the inner view size didn't animate at all because the method used to change the bounds doesn't seem to affect children.